# Java synchronization/locking

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I'm relatively new to concurrency in Java (still have yet to read JCIP, but it's on my list!) and I have a question regarding locking behavior.  Specifically, does Java lock on the reference of an object, or on the object itself?

Code example (not an sscce because I don't know how to demo this behavior in practice):

```
static final Object lockA = new Object();

public void method1() {
    synchronized(lockA) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}

public void method2() {
    Object lockB = lockA;
    synchronized(lockB) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

If another thread is executing `method1()` (and therefore has a lock on `lockA`), will `method2()` be allowed to execute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Synchronization is done on the object, so the synchronized block in `method2` will need to wait for the synchronized block in `method1` to finish.

Each object has an "intrinsic lock" associated with it (see [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)).  The synchronized block uses the intrinsic lock associated with the object on which you are synchronizing.

Answer (score 3):

No, `method2()` will block since the two methods are synchronizing on the same object (`lockB` is merely a reference pointing to the same object as `lockA`).